# Generate XML sitemap in Sitecore JSS

Tags: jss, sitemap

I am using `Sitecore 10` and `Angular JSS` without `SXA`, I did not install it, so my question is how I can generate an `XML sitemap` to our site?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I do not have idea about how to create it, and what i found in sitecore documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/configure-a-sitemap.html related to SXA. so i need to know how i can generate it while iam using JSS not SXA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate an XML sitemap by inheriting the `sitemap SXA templates` on the `JSS` settings template.

Please inherit the base template named `_SitemapSettings` from below mentioned path to the `JSS` setting template

```
/sitecore/templates/Feature/Experience Accelerator/SiteMetadata/Sitemap/_SitemapSettings
```

And another template named `_Sitemap` from below mentioned path to the corresponding route template you have created.

`/sitecore/templates/Feature/Experience Accelerator/SiteMetadata/Sitemap/_Sitemap`

You can also check out the detailed blog about this on the below link. (For transparency, this is my personal blog post).

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/steps-enable-sxa-sitemapxml-robotstxt-feature-sitecore-nijas-hameed/

Answer (score 0):

To generate the sitemap, you will still need to go through the Sitecore Pipelines. The pipeline responsible for the sitemap would be `httpRequestBegin`.

Even if you are not using SXA, you may try to see how the sitemap has been implemented. Moreover, there are many online resources on how to implement sitemap on Sitecore, examples:

- [Creating Sitemap without Using any module](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11462/creating-sitemap-without-using-any-module)
- [Generate Sitemap.xml with Sitecore](https://vinayakchauhandotcom.wordpress.com/2017/04/15/sitemap-xml-with-sitecore/)

If you want to see how the sitemap is implemented in SXA, you can check the following namespace

```
Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.SitemapHandler, Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata
```

Comment: I'm not sure this really classifies as an answer for the OP question.  The user is using a headless approach and therefore generating a sitemap via the CD server will likely not suffice here, since they'll need the sitemap generated on their rendering host(s).

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided are correct but will work only in connected mode of Sitecore jss, Incase you are using Sitecore headless topology which is widely used and promoted by Sitecore.
For Headless topology we make SSR app for React.js and Angular, to render our js application using Sitecore CD content fetch though layoutService or GraphQL.

By following the other answers, you will be able to access sitemap.xml on sitecore CD url but on SSR url you will be getting 404.

In SSR, go to config.ts, in excluded routes add 'sitemap.xml', or in .env file add sitecore CD sitemap.xml url. Restart the SSR.

Now you will be able to access Sitemap.xml in SSR url.

Happy Sitecoring !